# How do i put a shortcut icon in the launcher and delete it from the desktop?

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, icons

With play on Linux shortcuts are added to the desktop. I would like to keep it as clean as possible, so instead I'd prefer it to be on the launcher.
And in general when I drag and drop something onto the launcher then I can not delete it without the launcher icon being deleted aswell. Any ideas as to why this happens? Any help would be much appreciated. Also please use step by step explanation in answers as I am a relative new user. The Ubuntu release is the 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

The launcher links to the desktop icon you deleted. You can move the desktop icon to another (hidden) folder. Then drag it onto the launcher.

Comment: The recommended hidden directory would be `~/.local/share/applications/`.